# AWS/Terraform: Is there a way to toggle the replication_configuration block on an aws_s3_bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I am looking for suggestions on how I can toggle the `replication_configuration` block on an [`aws_S3_bucket` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket.html).

I am trying to have the `replication_configuration` block be applied only if my variable `enable_crr` is set to `true` in terraform.

The issue I face is that the block doesn't support `enabled` or `count`, so I'm hoping someone knows an alternative way of implementing this.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a way that works...
I added some logic to do two things:

1) `${var.enable_replication} == true ? <my backup bucket> : <a placeholder bucket arn>}`

2) I toggle the replication status between `Enabled / Disabled`

By doing this, if it's enabled it points to my backup bucket, and if its disabled it points to my placeholder bucket.

edit: if you're reading this, in version 0.12.x you can use `dynamic`to do this.